# Open file in Preview

Tags: applescript

I struggle with a basic file operation in Apple Script. A pdf is (successfully) written in the script like this:

```
theDocument's writeToURL:targetFile
```

Now I want to open the file in Preview like this:

```
tell application "Preview"
    activate
    open targetFile
end tell
```

I also tried this:

```
tell application "Preview"
    activate
    open POSIX path of targetFile
end tell
```

to no avail. I somehow seem to lack an understanding how to get the path to a given file.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn’t show what `targetFile` is, but assuming from the first line it’s an `NSURL` you need to convert it to an AppleScript file type before passing it to Preview’s `open` command:

```
set targetFile to targetFile's |path|() as string as POSIX file
```

AppleScript’s Apple event bridge doesn’t accept ObjC classes, only native AS types.

Comment: Thanks for that! Wow – I would have never figured that one out myself. Can you direct me to a source where I can learn about stuff like this more?

Comment: @ArminHierstetter  You can also coerce the `NSURL` value (which, here, will reference a file URL that we know exists) straight into an `alias`, which _Preview_ can open.  Therefore, after the `writeToURL:` method has completed writing, simply: **`tell application "Preview" to open the targetFile as alias`**